# Are Apple Live Photos supported on Linux?

Tags: linux, video, iphone, ios

I have a lot of [Live Photos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35286486) that I took with my iPhone.

Is there any Linux application that supports viewing this combination of a photo and video file? I know I can split the photo and video parts into different files, but I am looking for an convenient way to enjoy these photos as they were meant to, i.e. with their video part intact.